# Format terminal output to show apt-get upgrade errors in RED

Tags: apt, colors

I have a very simple bash script written for my Kali Linux distro so I don't have to run 
`apt-get update`, `apt-get upgrade`, `apt-get dist-upgrade`, `apt-get autoclean`, and `apt-get autoremov`e every time I open my laptop.

After reading up on the syntax for a few days I still can't get it correct. I'm trying to add something in the script to format the terminal output where it will show "Errors" in RED. Any help would be greatly appreciated in adding something to my script which will show errors in RED for apt-get upgrade output. Thank you in advance.

Just FYI here is my two line script...

```
apt-get update && apt-get upgrade -y && apt-get dist-upgrade -y && apt-get autoremove -y && apt-get autoclean -y
```

Comment: Can you give examples of which lines are errors and which lines are normal?

Comment: Well, you know when running apt-get upgrade and it will go through all the output of upgrading the packages. It doesn't specify where the errors are, I have to scroll through the entire output and look for them. I want them to show up in RED so I don't have to spend 5 minutes searching. The normal output is the same as output with errors, it will just say "error:" somewhere in all the output and keep on going with the next upgrade with no hiccups.

Comment: Actually, let me rephrase, I just want to have the word "error" show up in red....then I can quickly find where the errors are. Don't necessarily need the actual errors show up in red, just the word error in the output

Comment: Try `(apt-get update && apt-get upgrade -y && apt-get dist-upgrade -y && apt-get autoremove -y && apt-get autoclean -y) 2>&1 | grep -i --color -C 3000 "error"` ; does that look like the output you want?

Comment: I'm not sure how to force an error now on upgrading a package with apt-get upgrade, but i changed my script to reflect your answer and it works just fine. I'm going to try to force an error using the new script, i really appreciate the help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've written a little script that will color whatever string you give it:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use Getopt::Std;
use strict;
use Term::ANSIColor; 

my %opts;
getopts('hic:l:',\%opts);
    if ($opts{h}){
      print<<EoF; 
Use -l to specify the pattern(s) to highlight. To specify more than one 
pattern use commas. 

-l : A Perl regular expression to be colored. Multiple expressions can be
     passed as comma separated values: -l foo,bar,baz
-i : makes the search case sensitive
-c : comma separated list of colors;

EoF
      exit(0);
    }

my $case_sensitive=$opts{i}||undef;
my @color=('bold red','bold blue', 'bold yellow', 'bold green', 
           'bold magenta', 'bold cyan', 'yellow on_magenta', 
           'bright_white on_red', 'bright_yellow on_red', 'white on_black');
if ($opts{c}) {
   @color=split(/,/,$opts{c});
}
my @patterns;
if($opts{l}){
     @patterns=split(/,/,$opts{l});
}
else{
    $patterns[0]='\*';
}

# Setting $| to non-zero forces a flush right away and after 
# every write or print on the currently selected output channel. 
$|=1;

while (my $line=<>) 
{ 
    for (my $c=0; $c<=$#patterns; $c++){
    if($case_sensitive){
        if($line=~/$patterns[$c]/){
           $line=~s/($patterns[$c])/color("$color[$c]").$1.color("reset")/ge;
        }
    }
    else{
        if($line=~/$patterns[$c]/i){
          $line=~s/($patterns[$c])/color("$color[$c]").$1.color("reset")/ige;
        }
      }
    }
    print STDOUT $line;
}
```

If you save it as `color` in a directory that is in your `$PATH` and make it executable (`chmod +x /usr/bin/color`), you can color whatever you like:

```
sudo apt-get install nonexistent-package 2>&1 | color -l "E:,error"
```

The `2>&1` is needed to redirect error messages to the standard output.

Comment: That is awesome, so when installing packages the E: and word "error" will show up in red using that command, what about when running apt-get upgrade, and getting an error in all that output? Say I have dependency problems, get an error, and ive got 200+ lines of output....how do I get the word "error" in red so it sticks out instead of me scrolling through reading every line to find an error...

Comment: @WillHughes run all of your commands [grouped](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Command-Grouping.html), then redirect their output to the `color` script: `{ apt-get update && apt-get upgrade -y && apt-get dist-upgrade -y && apt-get autoremove -y && apt-get autoclean -y; } 2>&1 | color -l "E:|error"`. To make the entire line red, use `color -l "E:.*|error.*"`

Answer (score 1):

You can use hhlighter. You will need git and ack (possibly ack-grep depending on your distro).

```
git clone https://github.com/paoloantinori/hhighlighter.git
```

You can edit your .bashrc file in two ways. You could add a the path to your h.sh file like this:

```
. ~/hhlighter/h.sh
```

or you could just copy and paste the h() function into .bashrc. Either way, you will have to log out and back in to restart bash or you can run the following command:

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

Example usage:

```
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade -y | h -i error
```

or

```
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade -y | h -i error:
```

Click here for more info: [github.com/paoloantinori/hhighlighter](https://github.com/paoloantinori/hhighlighter)

Comment: #mchid I am having problems getting hhighlighter working on my distro. Do you think you would be able to help me out, if so I will describe what is happening. Seems easy but I can't figure out what is going on.

Comment: @WillHughes sure, what's up? did you already do `sudo apt-get install ack-grep`?

Comment: @WillHughes yeah, it seems it doesn't always work for highlighting output which is disappointing