# Why suddenly apt-get output became colored?

Tags: terminal, apt, colors, apt-key

I'm trying to get wine. I've been doing instructions from https://wiki.winehq.org/Ubuntu and on `sudo apt update` I've seen "E: The repository 'cdrom ..." with red "E". Just several minutes before in output of `sudo apt update` it was ordinary white same as the rest of output. Between "normal" and red the only commands I did were downloading w/out install `sudo apt-get install -d somepackage` and ones from the wine page.

I wanted to revisit/recheck what I've done and now only after `history` and `cat /etc/apt/sources.list.d/winehq-jammy.sources` output of `sudo apt update` is all white again.

Any idea what happened? What caused the colored output to apprear? I'm wary of glitches in the system I use, I want to find out the cause. Web search for colored output of apt found some solutions involving scripts etc., how adding sources and keys resulted in transient color?

TL;DR

Links found:

https://askubuntu.com/questions/445245/how-do-i-enable-fancy-apt-colours-and-progress-bars

[Format terminal output to show apt-get upgrade errors in RED](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/167828/format-terminal-output-to-show-apt-get-upgrade-errors-in-red)

Terminal contents (actually more commands than I mentioned ealier, still no idea how that resulted in color):

```
   35  sudo apt-get update
   36  sudo apt-get install -d somepackage
   37  eval $(apt-config shell CACHE Dir::Cache)
   38  eval $(apt-config shell ARCHIVES Dir::Cache::archives)
   39  # from man bash:
   40  # brace { after $ "serve to protect the variable to be expanded from characters immediately following it which could be interpreted as part of the name."
   41  debs_cache_folder=/${CACHE}/${ARCHIVES}
   42  echo $debs_cache_folder
   43  ls `echo $debs_cache_folder`
   44  ls `echo $debs_cache_folder` | wc
   45  sudo apt-get clean
... same  install -d  / ls wc / clean for several other packages 
   54  sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
   55  sudo mkdir -pm755 /etc/apt/keyrings
   56  sudo wget -O /etc/apt/keyrings/winehq-archive.key https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/winehq.key
   57  sudo wget -NP /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/dists/jammy/winehq-jammy.sources
   58  sudo apt update
   59  history
~/Downloads$ cat /etc/apt/sources.list.d/
cat: /etc/apt/sources.list.d/: Is a directory
~/Downloads$ cat /etc/apt/sources.list.d/
official-package-repositories.list  winehq-jammy.sources                
~/Downloads$ cat /etc/apt/sources.list.d/winehq-jammy.sources 
Types: deb
URIs: https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu
Suites: jammy
Components: main
Architectures: amd64 i386
Signed-By: /etc/apt/keyrings/winehq-archive.key
```

Comment: In item 35, the command you ran is `sudo apt-get update`, whereas in 58 it is `sudo apt update` - the commands `apt-get` and `apt` are different, in particular `apt` produces colored output by default on my system

Comment: @steeldriver, thanks. Reperformance confirmed `apt` vs `apt-get`. Do you want to write a short answer or maybe the question is not worth remaining here and better be deleted?